# Variable's Value Not Changed

Tags: javascript

I have this code :

```
function loadCharacter(characterName) {
    var characterObject = {"Tri":"t"};

    socket.emit("loadCharacter", { "name" : characterName },function(dataFromServer) {
        console.log(dataFromServer);
        characterObject = dataFromServer;
    });

    return characterObject;
};

var localCharacter = loadCharacter("Gabriella");
console.log(localCharacter);
```

`console.log(dataFromServer)` displays data from the server as it should be, but `console.log(localCharacter)` displays the original value, `{"Tri":"t"}`, instead of `dataFromServer`'s value.

How to change `characterObject`'s value and return it?

Comment: Get used to async JS, using callbacks. It's everywhere. No return values anymore, only callbacks. The callback is `function(dataFromServer)` so `loadCharacter()` doesn't have a return value.

Comment: your function returns the value before it is changed by the callback

Answer (score 0):

This is because

```
characterObject = dataFromServer;
```

...is run after

```
return characterObject;
```